# How can I insert the skill name inside the progress bar?

Tags: html, css

I am working on my resume and I want the skill name inside the progress bar, and not above. But I dont get it. Thx

this is the web: http://working.virgiliodelavega.com/

```
  <span class="skills-each">Illustrator</span> 
<div class="progress-bar blue"> 
<span style="width: 90%"></span> 
</div>
```

---

```
.skills-title {
    font-size: 1em;
}

.skills-each {
    font-size: .8em;
}

.progress-bar {
    background-color: #727e7f;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 3px;
}

.progress-bar span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;   
}

.blue span {
    background-color: #34495e;   
}

.red span {
    background-color: #e74c3c;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a change in markup.  Using lists is a lot cleaner than divs/spans.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/Hikxp

```
ul.skills {
  padding: 0;
}

ul.skills li {
  background-color: #727e7f;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

ul.skills li span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: .8em;
}

ul.skills li:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  content: '';
}

ul.skills li.seven:after {
  width: 70%;
}

ul.skills li.eight:after {
  width: 80%;
}

ul.skills li.nine:after {
  width: 90%;
}

ul.skills li.ten:after {
  right: 3px;
}

ul.skills.graphic li:after {
    background-color: #34495e;   
}

ul.skills.web li:after {
    background-color: #e74c3c;   
}

<h1>Graphic Skills</h1>

<ul class="skills graphic">
  <li class="eight"><span>Illustrator</span></li> 
  <li class="ten"><span>Photoshop</span></li> 
  <li class="nine"><span>Indesign</span></li> 
</ul>

<h1>Web Development</h1>

<ul class="skills web">
  <li class="seven"><span>Illustrator</span></li> 
  <li class="eight"><span>Photoshop</span></li> 
  <li class="nine"><span>Indesign</span></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Thx. I will check this as an option.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can try this way if you want

html

```
<span class="skillEachWrap"> <span class="skills-each">Illustrator</span></span>
<div class="progress-bar blue"> 
<span style="width: 90%"></span> 
</div>
```

css

```
.skillEachWrap {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.skills-each {
    font-size: .8em;
    position:absolute;
    top:7px;
    left:10px;
}
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/KTAGm/3/) hope this help you.....

Comment: hi is what you main the distance of the `.progress-bar` in each other, you can add `margin-bottom` in your `.progress-bar` [click me](http://jsfiddle.net/KTAGm/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:absolute` to place the text on top of your progress bar. Then use `line-height:25px` to center the text vertically within the bar. I also recommend you give you bar a class and not just target it as `span` since we have multiple children in `.progress-bar` now.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/4SN7J/1/)

[image: demo]

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress-bar blue">
    <span class="bar" style="width: 80%"></span>
    <span class="name">Photoshop</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.progress-bar {
    background-color: #727e7f;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 3px;

    position:relative;
}

.progress-bar .bar {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}

.progress-bar.blue .bar {
    background-color: #34495e;
}

.progress-bar .name {
    color:#FFF;
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    line-height:25px;
}
```

Comment: Thx. I am using ur code, but the grey .progress-bar fill all http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/4SN7J/1/

Comment: What browser are you using?